# BIML - 'AstTableNode' does not contain a definition for 'GetDropAndCreateDdl'

Tags: ssis, biml

I am working on a BIML project to generate SSIS packages.  I have a separate static class for utility methods.

I am attempting to call GetDropAndCreateDdl() to get the DDL from the souce to dynamically create a table in the destination.  This should work in theory as it is referenced in multiple posts: [here](http://bimlscript.com/walkthrough/Details/3121) and [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9097/biml-tutorial-creating-destination-tables/) as samples.

When generating the BIML, running the sample code below, I receive an error: *Error: 'AstTableNode' does not contain a definition for 'GetDropAndCreateDdl' and no accessible extension method 'GetDropAndCreateDdl' accepting a first argument of type 'AstTableNode' could be found*

> ```
> public static string GetDropAndCreateDDL(string connectionStringSource, string sourceTableName)
> {
>     var sourceConnection = SchemaManager.CreateConnectionNode("Source", connectionStringSource);
>     var sourceImportResults = sourceConnection.ImportTableNodes(Nomenclature.Schema(sourceTableName),Nomenclature.Table(sourceTableName));
>     return sourceImportResults.TableNodes.ToList()[0].GetDropAndCreateDdl();
>
> }
> ```

(Let's ignore the possibility of getting no table back or multiples for the sake of simplicity)

Looking at the [varigence documentation](https://docs.varigence.com/biml/api-reference/Varigence.Languages.Biml.Table.AstTableNode), I don't see any reference to this method.  This makes me think that there is a utility library that I am missing in my includes.

- using Varigence.Biml.Extensions;
- using Varigence.Biml.CoreLowerer.SchemaManagement;

What say you?

Joe

Comment: What source are you using for connectinStringSource? OLE, ADO, ODBC?

Comment: Using the native client (SQLNCLI11.1).

Comment: Future readers, if you were wondering why I was asking about the source type, SQL Server and OLE providers are good. Some other RDBMSes and ODBC seem less good for getting a database converted into a Biml representation. Also, `GetDatabaseSchema` is the newer, preferred method over `ImportTableNodes` I'd like to Cathrine's blog posts on the matter but her site is offline :(

Comment: ImportTableNodes was selected because I could filter on schema/table; as near as I can tell, GetDatabaseSchema is all or nothing.  I am only generating certain targeted tables, so for my implementation, the full DB Schema is overkill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetDropAndCreateDdl` is an extension method in  `Varigence.Biml.Extensions.SchemaManagement.TableExtensions`

`ImportTableNodes` returns an instance of
`Varigence.Biml.CoreLowerer.SchemaManagement.ImportResults` and the `TableNodes` is an `IEnumerable` of `AstTableNodes`

So, nothing weird there (like the table nodes in the import results being a different type)

I am not running into an issue if I have the code in-line with BimlExpress.

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
<#
string connectionStringSource = @"Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=localhost\dev2017;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=msdb";

var sourceConnection = SchemaManager.CreateConnectionNode("Source", connectionStringSource);
List<string> schemaList = new List<string>(){"dbo"};
var sourceImportResults = sourceConnection.ImportTableNodes("dbo", "");
WriteLine("<!-- {0} -->", sourceImportResults.TableNodes.Count());
//var sourceImportResults = sourceConnection.ImportTableNodes(schemaList,null);
var x = sourceImportResults.TableNodes.ToList()[0];
var ddl = x.GetDropAndCreateDdl();
WriteLine("<!-- {0} -->", sourceImportResults.TableNodes.FirstOrDefault().GetDropAndCreateDdl());

#>
</Biml>
```

The above code results in the following expanded Biml

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
  <!-- 221 -->
  <!-- IF EXISTS (SELECT * from sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[autoadmin_backup_configuration_summary]') AND type IN (N'V'))
DROP VIEW [dbo].[autoadmin_backup_configuration_summary]
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[autoadmin_backup_configuration_summary]  AS
SELECT 
    ManagedBackupVersion,
    IsAlwaysOn,
    IsDropped,
    IsEnabled,
    RetentionPeriod,
    EncryptionAlgorithm,
    SchedulingOption,
    DayOfWeek,
    COUNT(*) AS DatabaseCount
FROM autoadmin_backup_configurations
GROUP BY
    ManagedBackupVersion,
    IsAlwaysOn,
    IsDropped,
    IsEnabled,
    RetentionPeriod,
    EncryptionAlgorithm,
    SchedulingOption,
    DayOfWeek

GO

 -->
</Biml>
```

Comment: Winner: using Varigence.Biml.Extensions.SchemaManagement;

Comment: What's weird is that I didn't have to explicitly add a reference/using statement for it in the above code but perhaps something with pattern is requiring the explicit include. Glad it's working

Comment: it could be because I was using an external .cs class file rather than inline as in your example above.